# How to read all unknown Form parameters from POST method of Jersey consumes MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED

Tags: java, rest, post, jersey, put

The `MultivaluedMap` (jersey) is empty for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type, and the parameters are unknown thus can't use `@FormParam`.

This only happens for **POST** http method, but with **PUT** method everything works as expected. That is MultivaluedMap is not empty for PUT request for the same content-type.

Below is the code snippet.

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public Response processPostRequestFormURLEncodedMedia(
        @HeaderParam(REFERER) String referer,
        @Context final UriInfo uriInfo,
        @Context final HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
        @Context final Request request,
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {
  ...
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you use `Form` instead of `MultivaluedMap`?

Comment: This is a known issue. From what I remember there should even be a logged warning about it, saying that you should use `@FormParam`. I forgot how I got around this before. Had to do with extracting it using a property from the ContainerRequest.

Comment: Ok, I didn't try it. But I think this is what I did. Inject the `ContainerRequest` with `@Context` into the method, then use `cr.getProperty(InternalServerProperties.FORM_DECODED_PROPERTY)`. I think that should return a `Form`. I'm guessing from briefly looking at [the source code](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/WebComponent.java#L632)

Comment: Thanks, Peeskillet for your valuable time and feedback, with your sollution I could solv the issue.